# Python can't find automlconfig and automlrun

Tags: python, azure, automl

I'm working on azure from past few months, and everything was working fine, and now I'm having issues, I cant import automlconfig and automlrun from azureml.train.automl. I have tried all possible solutions, even azure jupyter-vm which by default must have all these libraries but no success yet. I cant find this issue on there forums, any help or advice would be great.

error text:- (cannot import name 'AutoMLConfig',cannot import name 'AutoMLrun')

Comment: Can you show the exact import statement you are running? Also, are you running this in any virtual environment? The version of python and automl libraries might help here as well

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following steps to see if it helps or not?

1. Completely uninstalled conda and reinstalled
2. Built the azure_automl env using azure_automl.cmd
3. Got from azureml.train.automl import AutoMLConfig to work.

Please let me know if you still have problem.

Regards,

Yutong